# get the current user id in twig symfony 3.4

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

i am using FosUserBundle in Symfony  3.4 i want to get the current user id and pass it in URL to another page from twig , this is my  code :

```
<a href="{{ absolute_url(asset('')) }}app_dev.php/ajout/{{ event.id }}/{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %} {{  app.user.id|number_format  }}
{% endif %}">Réserver</a>
```

but the problem is i get the url like this

```
http://localhost/techeventsweb/web/app_dev.php/ajout/1/%202
```

the id is '%202' while it's supposed to be an integer '2'

Comment: It looks like you have a space  before {{ app.user.id ...

Comment: @IwanWijaya thanks it'w working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have an User in your app session, you can fetch all your User information from Twig with this: `{{ app.user }}`
Then, to get the User Id, use `{{ app.user.id }}`

Some remarks, if you really want to set the url manually, This is the best practice:

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
    {% set url = absolute_url(asset('')) ~ 'app_dev.php/ajout/' ~ event.id ~ '/' ~ app.user.id %}
{% else %}
    {% set url = "OTHER_URL" %}
{% endif %}

<a href="{{ url }}">Réserver</a>
```

Comment: Ok :-) nice to have helped you